# insert multiple elements in string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to build a string like this

```
{ name: "john", url: "www.dkd.com", email: "john@fkj.com" }
```

where john, www.dkd.com and john@fkj.com are to be supplied by variables

I tried to do the following

```
s1 = "{'name:' {0},'url:' {1},'emailid:' {2}}"
s1.format("john","www.dkd.com","john@fkj.com")
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'name"
```

Dont able to understand what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to build (malformed)  JSON or a weird way of just building a string of a dictionary...

```
d = {'name': 'bob', 'email': 'whatever', 'x': 'y'}
print str(d)
```

Or:

```
import json
print json.dumps (d)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `{` and `}` by doubling them:

```
s1 = "{{'name:' {0},'url:' {1},'emailid:' {2}}}"
print s1.format("john","www.dkd.com","john@fkj.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the string formatting, which should work perfectly..

```
s1 = "{'name:' '%s','url:' '%s','emailid:' '%s'}" % ("john","www.dkd.com","john@fkj.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you didn't escaped the starting curly bracket, which is then interpreted by `format()` as a `named field`

As mentioned in the [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) documentation :

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

So:

```
s1 = "{{'name:' {0},'url:' {1},'emailid:' {2}}}"
print s1.format("john","www.dkd.com","john@fkj.com")
```

will output:

```
"{'name:' john,'url:' www.dkd.com,'emailid:' john@fkj.com}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your required format, this should work:

```
>>> s1 = "{name: '%s',url: '%s',emailid: '%s'}" % ("john","www.dkd.com","john@fkj.com")
>>> s1
"{name: 'john',url: 'www.dkd.com',emailid: 'john@fkj.com'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could simply do this the easy way:

```
print '''{ name: "''' + name + '''", url: "''' + url + '''", email: "''' + email + '''" }'''
```

here is the working solution http://ideone.com/C65HnB